# Is it possible to use the threads/locals window when debugging a user process from kernel mode WinDBG?

Tags: windows, windbg

I'm debugging a filter driver and looking at where explorer is stuck in said driver.  Here's explorer:

```
PROCESS 86cce2a0  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0b98    Peb: 7ffdb000  ParentCid: 0aac
    DirBase: 3f4ca3e0  ObjectTable: 00000000  HandleCount:   0.
    Image: explorer.exe
```

I can now:

```
!process 86cce2a0 17
```

To show full user and kernel mode stacks of explorer.  However, I'd like to be able to use the UI threads/locals/stacks windows in WinDBG.  Does anyone know how to set those up?  If explorer crashes WinDBG automatically sets those windows up properly (I can even see the source code of my explorer shell extension) so it must be possible.

I've tried:

```
.process 86cce2a0
```

But that doesn't cut it with regards to the UI.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the call stack and locals part of it.  The part I was missing was `/r`, after listing the threads with `!process <address> 17`, it's possible to:

```
.thread /r 86d6dd48
```

This sets up the call stack windows and locals windows.  The only thing I'm missing is the threads window but perhaps I can live without that.